# Symfony RememberMeToken - no cookies is set

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, cookies

I am using Symfony2, here is my firewalls section from security.yml:

```
# ...

firewalls:
    default:
        remember_me:
            name:       RememberMeName
            key:        "%secret%"
            lifetime:   31536000 # 365 days
            path:       /
            domain:     ~
            always_remember_me: true
        anonymous: ~
        http_basic: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: /auth
            csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
            remember_me: true
        logout:
            delete_cookies:
                RememberMeName: { path: /, domain: null }
            path:   /logout
            target: /
```

Here is my auth process (I do it manually):

```
    if ($form->get('remember_me')->getData()){
        $token = new RememberMeToken($profile, 'default', $secret);
    } else {
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($profile, $profile->getPassword(), 'default', $profile->getRoles());
    }
    $controller->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);

    $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($controller->get('request'), $token);
    $controller->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch('security.interactive_login', $event);
```

Problem: No cookie is set after RememberMe auth (but $token is `RememberMeToken`)

Answer (score 0):

I was in your shoes last week, but I figured it out. Remembermetoken has nothing to do with it(I wasted a lot of time messing with that and it turned out to be useless)Eventually I used TokenBasedRememberMeServices

```
//use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\TokenBasedRememberMeServices;

$key = $this->container->getParameter('secret'); 

    $rememberMeService = new TokenBasedRememberMeServices(
            array($this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('BrandonSecurityBundle:User')), 'divine_office_hub_1234567', $key, array(
        'path' => '/',
        'name' => 'remember',
        'domain' => null,
        'secure' => false,
        'httponly' => true,
        'lifetime' => 315360000, // forever
        'always_remember_me' => true,
        'remember_me_parameter' => '_remember_me2')
    );



   $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, "api", $user->getRoles());
 $this->get("security.context")->setToken($token); 
  $this->get('session')->set('_security_main', serialize($token));


$request = $this->get("request");
  $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
$this->get("event_dispatcher")->>dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);
```

and in security.yml I had

```
   api: 
            remember_me:
                key:      divine_office_hub_1234567
                lifetime: 31536000
                name: remember
                always_remember_me: true
                remember_me_parameter: _remember_me2
                path: ~
```

So you know if you want to adapt this to your code, and to answer anyone getting stuck at this(I was stuck for over 2 weeks)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also tried `TokenBasedRememberMeServices` and I get cookies set correctly, but when user (with no session) enters the site - he get **no info from cookies** :( Sooo... I write my own `SecurityListener`, `SecurityProvider`, `SecurityToken` and `Factory`... I read and write cookie manually (using `Request` and `Response` objects) and all works fine now.

Comment: I had a problem with the user not being able to log in from the cookie although the cookie existed, and that turned out to be because of the remember_me_parameter it had to be unique to it. Your solution is too complicated. I was too stubborn to make it work as I hate writing extra classes :D

Comment: Yes, it's very complicated. But it has great documentation in symfony cook book and you can handle every small part of your auth process.